# root folder linux server

Tags: html, linux, root

I have inherited a site which the css links on all of the 100+ pages are relative to the root. For example they are

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Locally this is fine locally but remotely the .html file is looking at the root folder when actually the files are in

http://myserver.com/thesitefolder

is there a way to do this via .htaccess or another way? I think a sub directory would work but is there a qucik way to fix this?

Comment: I think you forgot to add the example. Also your question isn't entirely clear: is there a way to do what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set up a DNS A-Record for thesite.myserver.com pointing to IP of myserver.com
- Set up Apache virtualhost for thesite.myserver.com pointing to the root directory

Now your site folder (for the new virtual host) is the root folder